# Is there a way to call function in android from html5 without using Webview

Tags: javascript, android, html

I wanted to call a function in android when any change is made in website. So for this I need javascript call a function in android when a change is made.

I know we do that using `addJavaScriptInterafce` when we are using webviews.
But I don't use web views for this.

So is there a way to call without webviews?

Comment: The only way I can think of without webview would be making an http request and comparing the last response with the new one. If something changed, then you can call your function.

Comment: @SebastianBreit But in my case Android app will not know when a change will be made. So we can't keep on making such calls to see if any change is made

Comment: How do you display HTML without `WebView`?

Comment: @fishbone I dont need to display Html. Android app should just need to know when a change is made by user in html5 website

Comment: You can use push-messages to notify Android device about changes. I think it is the most simple solution.

Comment: @fishbone Its not the android device that should be notified. A function in android code should be notified

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream) to make downstream messaging to your application. Create service that extends GcmListenerService to handle messages that you send the when website is updated and start the function or the activity you like.